# Moodle: Hide the footer

Tags: css, moodle

I'm new to Moodle and I have just a very basic knowledge of css.
I have installed a theme in moodle and there is a very annoying footer at the top of the page.
I wanted to change the background color or hide it via CSS but I can't find the CSS file.

In the theme folder there are some css file, but even if I delete everything, the footer stays with this annoying background color.

When I inspect it with chrome I see this.

[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IToo.png)

I just want to edit the CSS file, but I can't find it.
I have the feeling that this css settings are generated dinamically somehow, but I really have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Moodle is a PHP framework, but it is designed to be edited through the administration interface. If you have access, you can make edits to the theme there. If you have access to the code, you should be able to locate the theme folder (should be named similarly to your theme), and that will contain the relevant CSS files you need to edit

Comment: I have admin access and all the files about this theme are in /theme/
I found some css files with the footer setting but even changing them there is no effect.

( Please take a look at the link to the image )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get the css file in paticular moodle theme by

```
your moodle -> theme -> your theme -> style -> some.css
```

After any customization on css file of theme, for reflect you need to do purge all cache by

```
Site administration > Development > Purge all caches
```

Because moodle does cache for CSS and javaScript to increase the performance.

If you will not comfort with purge all cache after every changes in css, then you can enable the 'Theme Designer Mode ` option on theme setting page. You can get this page by

```
Site Administration > Appearance > Themes > Theme settings
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Site Administration > Appearance > Additional HTML`;

Add the style below into the section `Before head`:

```css
<style> #page-footer { display: none !important; } </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following CSS code in the Custom CSS textbox.

```
/* 
  To remove the Moodle picture in the footer (from Emma, thanks.) 
*/
.homelink {display:none}
.sitelink {display:none}
```